# window.opener.focus() problem in FF5+

Tags: javascript, firefox-5, firefox6

I'm opening new window with next code:
    `window.open(url,pageName1,"menubar=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,status=yes,width=1050,height=820");`

so window is not modal

In new window I'm calling:

`if (window.opener) window.opener.focus();`

in IE, Chorme, FF3.6 parent window become in focus, BUT not in FF5 or FF6, how I can move focus to parent window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FF4+ prevernt window raising and lower by default, you can enable in options:
Tools->Options->Content->Advanced... (in "Enable JavaScript" row)->Check "Raise or lower windows"

Answer (score 1):

I'm leaving here my contribution to anyone wants to open popup in background. The secret is open a blank page, then inject the desired url.

```
<script>
    var url = 'http://example.com/page.html';
    var popunder = w.open('about:blank',"window_example", "resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=800,status=yes,top=0,left=0");

    if(window.navigator.userAgent.match(/firefox/i)){ //fix for firefox browser
        popunder.document.write('<script type="text/javascript">window.opener.open("","_parent");location.replace("'+url+'");</script>');
        popunder.document.close();
    } else
        popunder.parent.location = url;

    popunder.blur();
    window.focus();
</script>
```