# How to focus the parent page from child window in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am calling the parent page javascript function from child window with code below, which displays some alert message on parent page and closes the child window.

```
window.opener.CallAlert("test is"+test);
opener.focus();
self.close();
```

What is happening with above code snippet is alert comes on parent window but focus remains on child window. i need explicitly go to parent window. Once I click ok on alert child window closes.

Everything is fine but I want the to focus on parent window once i call the `window.opener.CallAlert()` from child window.

**Edit**

Looks like `opener.focus();` works on IE but not mozilla. Any workaround for firefox?

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that this is not guaranteed to work and is at the discretion of the browser.

See this thread: [window.opener.focus() doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501095/window-opener-focus-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

just try the obvious:

```
window.opener.focus();
```

Comment: it does not work. It works only when i maximize the popup. Without maximize it does not work.

Comment: see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281758/window-opener-focus-problem-in-ff5

Answer (score 0):

try with delay setTimeout(function(){self.close()},300) and then display alert on parent page. It will schedule to close the current window after some delay automatically with display of alert message on parent signal