# How return to parent window - onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

In the parent window, I have an onclick event that opens a (popup) child window (that contains a mp3 player, playing sample audio clips).

The child window is opened with:

```
<a href="#" onclick="popupwindow('popup.html', 'mp3Player',800,300 ); return false;">Mp3 Clips</a>
```

I assumed (wrongly;) I could return to the parent with:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.opener();">return to win</a>
```

How do I return to the parent (& leaving the child window open).

In the parent window the javascript function is:

```
function popupwindow(url, winName, w, h) {
  var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
  var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
  return window.open(url, winName, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=yes, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "return to parent"?

Comment: I have a html page that displays in a browser 'window', it includes a link that opens a popup window (commonly referred to as a 'child' window). The original window is therefore commonly referred to as its 'parent'

Comment: I have 19 years Javascript experience so I know all that, but what do you mean "*return* to parent"?

Comment: I want to display the original window.  i.e. give it focus

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.opener.focus() doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501095/window-opener-focus-doesnt-work)

Comment: Yes, thanks - possible duplication, but that was 5 yrs ago.
I've found that 'window.opener.close()' closes the parent window.
But 'window.opener.focus()' seems to do nothing.
So I don't understand why it's a security issue, when closing another window isn't.
Is there a solution?  I'm testing in IE11, does it work in other browsers?

Comment: whoops  - I'm testing in Chrome not IE

Comment: Just found that it DOES get focus in Safari

Answer (score 0):

I could not get Chrome to focus the parent window, so (like the solution from 5yrs ago) for now have chosen to close the parent window, and re-open it with the original url (luckily I know which url is the parent).

```
onclick=('window,opener.close();window.open("https:www.....","_blank");return false;')
```

Thanks everyone for your help & guidance,