# window.opener.focus() does not work in firefox.Any workaround?

Tags: javascript, html, focus

i am calling the parent page javascript  function from child window with below code to display alert  on
parent page and then closes the child window

```
     window.opener.CallAlert("test is"+test);
     window.opener.focus();
     self.close();
```

what happening is alert comes on parent window but focus remains on child window in firefox. user needs explicitly go to parent window .
Though it works like charm on IE,Chrome

Everything is fine but I want the to focus on parent window once i call the window.opener.CallAlert() from child window.
**Any workaround for this (if i can hide child window something like this)?**

I tried solution suggested at [window.opener.focus() problem in FF5+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281758/window-opener-focus-problem-in-ff5) (Tools->Options->Content->Advanced... (in "Enable JavaScript" row)->Check "Raise or lower windows") but that does not work too

Comment: Have you tried calling `focus()` from within the `CallAlert()` function in the parent? (Or perhaps, if FF doesn't allow raising/lowering windows without changing its settings, you could refactor `CallAlert()` slightly to make it asynchronous and then the child will have already closed itself and thus not retain focus.)